# How to upload courses un moodle with cohorts

Tags: php, moodle

As I can generate many courses using a CSV file and that there is cohorte1 indicate that automatic enrollment method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you meant:

**"I want to add courses via Moodle's Bulk Upload Courses features (From a CSV file) and I want the courses to automatically have a cohort enrolled onto them".**

If this is what you meant,

You do that by adding the enrolment method to your CSV file like so:

```
shortname,fullname,category,enrolment_1,enrolment_1_customint1
maths,Mathematics,some category,cohort,X
English,English Language,some other category, cohort, Y
```

Where "X" and "Y" are the IDs of the cohorts you'd like to enrol.

HTH

Comment: I upload this file, and print this error

shortname,fullname,category,enrolment_1,enrolment_1_customint1
Test,Test,242,cohort,94

Category: http://moodle/course/index.php?categoryid=242
Cohort: http://moodle/cohort/assign.php?id=94&returnurl=%2Fcohort%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3D0


Resultados de la carga de cursos
Detectado un error de codificación, debe ser corregido por un programador: moodle_database::update_record_raw() id field must be specified.

Más información sobre este error

The course is created, but not the associated

http://i.imgur.com/LuxybqX.png - http://pastebin.com/KsK53QjZ @Tim